# Maxwell's Demon bug, trapdoor space and time

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy, information

What about the size of the door (space) and how long has it to be opened (time)?

I think Maxwell's demon would have a problem with space, if the door is too wide (more than one particle size), then direct interaction between the two part is possible and would lead to lose isolation restriction, like there were no demon, (even no isolation wall). On the other hand, if the door is too narrow, then no particle can go into or it will let pass only those which are direct aimed, then Maxwell's demon would lose its freedom of choice because the narrow gate itself "choose" particles having a direction perpendicular to the wall, despite any module criterion (no temperature can be chosen) again it is like there were no demon.

Finally assuming that there were an exact size door being useful for the demon work, then time would be the problem, when the door is open too long, both side particles can cross or collide, like there were no demon!, and if the door is opened too little time, then it only could "select" fast particles from both sides,then it couldn't separate temperatures.

I've read very complex arguments against Maxwell's Demon, concerning information store but I think size and time constraint could be enough arguments to defeat Maxwell's Demon, **Do you know any related work about size and time constraint ?**

Thanks

Comment: The demon is assumed to be able to deal with these issues, and these question are of little consequence because limits on the performance of the system can be placed without knowing the answers to them. *Enter stage left: information theory*.

Comment: Yes, information seems to be a deeper limit, and I think in the same way, but how to avoid "the chicken or the egg dilemma ", I mean, what is the justification,  perhaps we have an equal strong limit in information and implementation, (like lack of data vs no existence of an algorithm) if you suppose inversely that the daemon magically has the information about every molecule How we are sure we could avoid implementation problems? and I don't mean technological problems, I mean an algorithmical, geometrical, logical imposibilty of a daemon even having the information.

Comment: Maxwell's demon has been implemented experimentally, and it  [actually works](http://www.scientificamerican.com/article.cfm?id=demonic-device-converts-inform). Information is indeed the solution to the paradox.

Comment: In addition to the above comments, I would point out that Maxwell's demon need not be perfect for the paradox to exist. Even if it lets, say, one particle go through the "wrong" way for each three that go the right way, the temperature difference will still increase (if the energies of these particles are roughly the same).

Answer (score 1):

Some of your concerns are valid, although irrelevant for the argument's sake. For instance, regarding the size of the door, the demon can have many doors across the wall and open only the one he needs, at the time it needs to. The likelihood of two particles coming from both sides at exactly the same time is almost nil, so if the daemon is fast enough he can always select the particle that he wants to cross to the other side.

Answer (score -2):

Let us imagine a baseball player that is also a Maxwell's demon, and perfectly elastic baseball balls, that are flying around randomly. When the demon sees a fast ball, he catches it with a baseball glove. Now the demon has already done what a demon is supposed to do: catch one or more fast molecules.

If the demon must collect many balls into a container, there is very little problem collecting a few balls into a large container. As the container fills up the demon must be smarter and quicker.

Oh yes, the demon could also just drop the ball. The glove heats up anyway. I mean the energy is collected in the molecules of the glove.

A demon whose temperature is 0 Kelvins does not need any energy at all. The warmer the demon the more energy its brain uses to compute. This is actually very simple!

[here is a story about some kind of maxwells demon device](http://www.nature.com/news/2010/101114/full/news.2010.606.html)

[here is a game where one can be a maxwells demon](http://www.gamegarage.com/game/maxwells-demon/)

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: OP asks about impossibility to catch fast molecules, I tell how it very clearly is possible. That was my related work. Is there some problem?

Comment: But Maxwell's demon doesn't just have to catch fast molecules, it has to separate them from the cold ones *without expending any energy*. As you've pointed out, in your scenario energy is going into the glove that the demon has to then get rid of. It's not that I don't think you couldn't build a Maxwell's demon that works this way, but I don't think you've actually demonstrated that you can.